# "Password Strength Unknown" Registration Issue

Tags: javascript, login, user-registration, signup

I encountered a strange bug when users are trying to enter a new password that states "Password Strength Unknown" **regardless of the amount of characters** (capitalized etc.) that are entered into the input field.

Direct link to site: https://www.uncvrd.co/wp-login.php?action=rp

Screenshot:
[image]

What other information can I provide to help solve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

If using an SSL when setting up your site it is very common to see this issue.

I found using

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = true;
```

At the top of wp-config.php fixes this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Found out the issue, for some reason beautifying the code before save messed with formatting. By downloading a fresh `wp-login.php` I was able to resolve this